# pandas, groupby but only upto certain number

Tags: pandas

I have a user behavior data. A user looks at items.

```
user_id, item_id, timestamp
1, a, 1000
2, b, 1001
1, c, 1002
1, d, 1004
1, e, 1005
1, a, 1006
2, f, 1007
```

Conceptually, I treat this viewing action happend in a session, and want to construct a session.

(If I could I would look at the timestamp and I could define session with it, but for simplicity I'm just partitioning with a fixed window size)

For a window size=3, and stride=1 (which will be clear in example), I want to transfrom the data to the following format

```
user_id, items 
1, [a,c,d]
2, [b,f]
1, [d, e, a]
```

So, for user_id 1, his/her first session comprises of viewing `[a,c,d]`, second session `[d,e,a]`. `d` is repeated because stride=1, if stride was 2, second session would be `[c,d,e]`

(When you partition data by window size, I want the windows overlap each other with size equal to stride)

If `stride` is too much hassle to implement, I would just drop it. (It's there because I'm arbiltrarilly partitioning the session and don't want to lose the sequential information)

Comment: I added to op.. (When you partition data by window size, I want the windows overlap each other with size equal to stride) .. hope it makes it clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function that should work. (I don't guarantee it behaves as you might expect when `stride > gsize`).  My definition of `stride` is slightly different. I take it as the number of observations since the first to begin a new grouping:

```
import pandas as pd

def rolling_list(x, stride=1, gsize=3):
    if len(x) <= gsize:
        l = [list(x.to_list())]
    else:
        l = [x.iloc[i*stride:(i*stride)+gsize].to_list()
             for i in range(len(x)//gsize+(gsize-stride))]
    return pd.Series(l)

df.groupby('user_id').item_id.apply(rolling_list, stride=1)

#user_id   
#1        0    [a, c, d]
#         1    [c, d, e]
#         2    [d, e, a]
#         3    [e, a, z]
#2        0       [b, f]

df.groupby('user_id').item_id.apply(rolling_list, stride=2)
#user_id   
#1        0    [a, c, d]
#         1    [d, e, a]
#         2       [a, z]
#2        0       [b, f]
#Name: item_id, dtype: object
```

#### Sample Data (added an extra row)

```
user_id,item_id,timestamp
1,a,1000
2,b,1001
1,c,1002
1,d,1004
1,e,1005
1,a,1006
2,f,1007
1,z,1008
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems [a,c,d] is type of ndarray and [b, f] is type of list.. having hard time with it, can you take a look and change it to list /series/np.array from ndarray?

Comment: @eugene I changed the `.to_numpy()` to `.to_list()`. Should work now